# SAP Reports(2013): Dynamic Page headers based from a parameter or database values

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, report

I am trying to figure out how to have a page header in SAP Reports 2013 which will automatically change based on the Month and Year of a parameter or date values from the database I'm linking it into (SQL Server 2008 R2), if possible.

I want the headers in bold below to be renamed based on a given Month and Year.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header take a formula field and write below code:

```
"Sales_Amt_"&table.Month&Table.Year
```

Comment: solved it mate. i just used my parameter from my stored procedure which is a datetime type then used the Year() & Month() fx in Crystal reports. the odd thing though is CReports interprets my parameter as string even though is a date. 

i also read it about here: https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1653915


but this solved it: cDate(ToText(cDate({?@dateMonthYear})))

thanks your answer led me to these functions ;)